# Passing 2 dimensional array created using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c

I've created a 2-D array in C using dynamic memory allocation.

```
int **x;

x=(int **)malloc(2*sizeof(int)); 

for(i=0;i<k;i++)

x[i]=(int*)malloc(K*sizeof(int));
```

Now, let us pass this array as a parameter to function called Sum.

```
Sum(x);
```

In the function `Sum(int *x[])`, the dimension in the square bracket cant be left empty, and I cannot initialize with a parameter that varies dynamically either.

Can you please show me a solution to this problem.

Comment: I didn't check this link before

Comment: `x=(int **)malloc(2*sizeof(int));` --> `x=(int **)malloc(k*sizeof(int*));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the function `Sum(int *x[])`, the dimension in the square bracket cant be left empty

Sure it can; in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are interpreted as `T *a`; all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`, not as an array of `T`.

You need to pass the array dimensions as separate parameters anyway so that `Sum` can do its job properly, but you can certainly declare `x` as `int *x[]` or even `int **x`.

If you're using a C99 compiler or a C2011 compiler that supports VLAs, you *can* use a runtime variable to size the array:

```
int Sum( size_t cols, int *x[cols] )
```

or even

```
int Sum( size_t rows, size_t cols, int x[rows][cols] )
```